# Can SQL return different results for two runs of the same query using ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestSort
(
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
Value int NOT NULL
)
```

The `Value` column could (and is expected to) contain duplicates.
Let's also assume there are already 1000 rows in the table.

I am trying to prove a point about unstable sorting.

Given this query that returns a 'page' of 10 results from the first 1000 inserted results:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TestSort WHERE Id <= 1000 ORDER BY Value
```

My intuition tells me that two runs of this query could return different rows if the `Value` column contains repeated values.

I'm basing this on the facts that:

- the sort is not stable
- if new rows are inserted in the table between the two runs of the query, it could possibly create a re-balancing of B-trees (the `Value` column may be indexed or not)

EDIT: For completeness: I assume rows never change once inserted, and are never deleted.

In contrast, a query with stable sort (*ordering also by Id*) should always return the same results, since `ID`s are unique:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TestSort WHERE Id <= 1000 ORDER BY Value, Id
```

The question is: Is my intuition correct? If yes, can you provide an actual example of operations that would produce different results (at least "on your machine")? You could modify the query, add indexes on the `Values` column etc.
I don't care about the exact query, but about the principle.

I am using MS SQL Server (2014), but am equally satisfied with answers for any SQL database.

If not, then why?

Comment: Demo https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375976 , check result 1 and 2. To see result in the same TOP (n) you should clear cache before runs. Cannot do it in provided environement so I use two queries.

Comment: @lad2025 Very interesting. But why? :)

Comment: @lad2025 Tried it locally, with cache clearing. Impressive! If you would consider expanding this to an answer, I would consider awarding the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ties when ordering the order by is not stable.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375976)**

```
CREATE TABLE #TestSort
(
Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
Value INT NOT NULL
) ;

DECLARE @c INT = 0;

WHILE @c < 100000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #TestSort(Value)
  VALUES ('2');

  SET @c += 1;
END
```

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM #TestSort 
ORDER BY Value
OPTION (MAXDOP 4);

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;  -- run to clear cache

SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM #TestSort 
ORDER BY Value
OPTION (MAXDOP 4);
```

The point is I force query optimizer to use parallel plan so there is no guaranteed that it will read data sequentially like Clustered index probably will do when no parallelism is involved.

You cannot be sure how Query Optimizer will read data unless you explicitly force to sort result in specific way using `ORDER BY Id, Value`.

For more info read **[`No Seatbelt - Expecting Order without ORDER BY`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx).**

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct.  In SQL, the sort for `order by` is not stable.  So, if you have ties, they can be returned in any order.  And, the order can change from one run to another.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) sort of explains this:

> Using OFFSET and FETCH as a paging solution requires running the query
>   one time for each "page" of data returned to the client application.
>   For example, to return the results of a query in 10-row increments,
>   you must execute the query one time to return rows 1 to 10 and then
>   run the query again to return rows 11 to 20 and so on. Each query is
>   independent and not related to each other in any way. This means that,
>   unlike using a cursor in which the query is executed once and state is
>   maintained on the server, the client application is responsible for
>   tracking state. To achieve stable results between query requests using
>   OFFSET and FETCH, the following conditions must be met:
>
> - The underlying data that is used by the query must not change. That is, either the rows touched by the query are not updated or all
>     requests for pages from the query are executed in a single transaction
>     using either snapshot or serializable transaction isolation. For more
>     information about these transaction isolation levels, see SET
>     TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL).
> - The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique.

Although this specifically refers to `offset`/`fetch`, it clearly applies to running the query multiple times without those clauses.

Comment: Actually, my real life query that started this question DOES use Offset/Fetch (it is generated by Linq to EF)

Answer (score -1):

I think this post will answer your question:

[Is SQL order by clause guaranteed to be stable ( by Standards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522746/is-sql-order-by-clause-guaranteed-to-be-stable-by-standards)

The result is everytime the same when you are in a single-threaded environment. Since multi-threading is used, you can't guarantee.

Comment: The result when ordering by non-unique columns is non-deterministic, even if single threaded.  The order of the rows returned may depend on the physical location of pages within the file, which may change due to database maintenance.

Comment: Don't think that the database maintenance is anything that will take effect here. I think we are talking about the same results just in antoher order. That means nothing has changed since the last statement ran.

Comment: If the order is different, the results are also different if limited by `TOP` or `OFFSET/FETCH`.  The result may vary by happenstance, according factors like the execution plan and physical storage of pages.