# Non-determinism in Spark - maybe from row_number()?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Apache Spark 1.5.2 through Python and there seems to be some non-determinism on the results. Further down the data pipeline - after some more joins and filters - the result table varies in its number of rows.

It's hard to extract the relevant example, but here is the structure that could be relevant (the other parts are simple joins, where, datediff, ...). It is using Spark SQL through `sqlContext.sql(...)`. I do `.cacheTable()` in between, too.:

```
select row_number() over(order by col1, col2 desc) as id, t.*
    from (select ... where ... group by ...) t
...
select count(1)
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
  on t1.id=t2.id
  where t2.id is null
```

Basically the last command gives different results every time it is called.

Can you see at which point there could be something non-deterministic?

EDIT: It has been proposed that row_number() is non-deterministic. While I am aware of that, something else is happening here. Apparently the non-determinism kicks in twice during a single execution, so that even a *self-join* from a single source produces incorrect results.

Comment: should that be where 2.id is NOT null?

Comment: No, it was null - trying to get all rows which don't have a match.

Comment: I looked carefully at this and was unable to come up with the reason. There was a bug fixed precisely in 1.5.2 that - prior to the fix - would have explained this.

Comment: Yes, I saw the bug. But Spark said it's 1.5.2.2. Also it seems when I dump the row_number table to disk, this non-determinism disappears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is SQL order by clause guaranteed to be stable ( by Standards)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522746/is-sql-order-by-clause-guaranteed-to-be-stable-by-standards)

Comment: Thanks, this led to me finding my issue. In my case, I had a tie situation that caused the row number to be different depending on how the ties were broken, thus causing different behaviour every time I ran the code