# Not understand SQL Limit

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm solving a problem about SQL on hackerrank. Here is the task:
Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
The STATION table is described as follows:

```
STATION
    Field    Type
    ID       NUMBER
    CITY     VARCHAR2(21)
    STATE    VARCHAR2(2)
    LAT_N    NUMBER
    LONG_W   NUMBER
```

Here is my code:

```
select
    city,
    length(city) as city_length
from
    station
order by
    city_length limit 1;
```

This returns: `Roy 3`

But when I use this code:

```
select
    city,
    length(city) as city_length
from
    station
order by
    city_length limit 10;
```

it returns:

```
    Amo 3
    Roy 3
    Lee 3
    Alba 4
    Neon 4
    Pony 4
    Taft 4
    Dale 4
    Yuma 4
    Odin 4
```

I'm quite confusing I think the second code will return `Roy 3` first rather than `Amo 3`

Comment: Try `order by city_length, city`, and see what you get.

Comment: there's no difference between your two queries besides the `LIMIT` number - please explain why you think `Roy 3` should come before `Amo 3`....

Comment: @jarlh This time it returns Amo 3

Comment: @Dai I think if sort city column in city_length order, It will be like this: `Amo 3, Roy 3, Lee 3, ...` then when use limit it will return `Amo 3`. But why use `limit 1` return different from `limit 10`

Comment: It's a bit interesting. But more important is to fully specify the sort order if you want a specific result order.

Comment: @nicole Please read-up on the concept of _stable sort_ - [SQL does not guarantee that `ORDER BY` will be _stable_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522746/is-sql-order-by-clause-guaranteed-to-be-stable-by-standards) which is why you get unexpected results when your `ORDER BY` criteria is _incomplete_ (i.e. you're getting _tied results_ and your `ORDER BY` does not specify a _tie-breaker_).

Comment: The root cause of the confusion is that `city, length(city)` requires `GROUP BY city`. The query is malformed as it is, but will run in MySQL 5.7, that is now obsolete. If this query runs in Hackerrank that wouldn't speak too well of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY
> names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters
> in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city,
> choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

This can be solved easily by

```
(
select city,length(city)  as city_length
from station order by length(city) asc, city asc limit 1 
  )
union all
(
select city,length(city) 
from station order by length(city) desc , city asc  limit 1
  )
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/ytvqRg2O)

Comment: very nice solution...

Answer (score -1):

```sql
(select city,(length(city))  from station where length(city)=(select min(length(city)) from station)order by city limit 1)
union 
(select city, length(city) from station order by length(city) desc limit 1)
```

Comment: How does this answers the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. Can you [edit] your answer and explain how it solves the posted question? At least you should learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.